# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser function to parse(get anchore tag) from html source

Tags: php-parser

I need to find a way to request the href & value of all `<a` elements from HTML file.

For example:

`<a href="http://domain.com" class="clsLink">Domain Link</a>`
Output:

```
href: 'http://domain.com'
value: 'Domain Link'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$html=file_get_html($url);
foreach ($html->find('a') as $links){

    //Get link text
    echo $links->innertext;

    //Get href value
    echo $links->href;
}
```